# Facebook Pixel activated 2 times

Tags: html, web, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to put the Facebook Pixel on my website but i have [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxYFC.jpg) on Chrome's Pixel Helper addon.

I have only pasted the js code they gave to me.

One more strange thing is that on the local website the addon says everything is good, but once only that's not the same and I don't understand why because I did'nt change any code.

Thank's for helping

Comment: I want to add that when I reload the page, the addon says there's no more problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it was because of an angularjs redirection I had on the root of my site. 
I put a condition in facebook pixel code to check with the url if I needed to load the pixel or not.

**EDIT :**

Here is the script in my index.html.
I look for '!#' in url, because the pixel was loading 2 times, once without '!#' and one with.

```
<script>
    // original script
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?   
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
        n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
            document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxx');
    // I check the url to see if there is the '#!' in it, if there is I don't load the pixel 
    var add = window.location.toString();
    if (add.indexOf("/#!/") != -1) {
        fbq('track', "PageView");
    }
</script>
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hey! I am currently experiencing the same issue! Do you think you could post how you inserted the conditional into the pixel code? Would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Thanks so much! Where you have "enter code here" this is where you are putting the "var add = window.location.toString()" etc..?

Comment: Ouch sorry the "enter code here" is the Stackoverflow default text :s
You just need to paste Facebook's pixel code and to put your if condition "fbq('track', "PageView");"  By checking url for example

Comment: @nocalis var add = window.location.toString();
        if (add.indexOf("/#!/") != -1) {
            fbq('track', "PageView");
        }-> This code need to add after which line i am using in react js.